# Insertion of node in a doubly linked list at last

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

If I execute the above code it and if there are 3 nodes such as 1->2->3 and the inserted element is 10 at 3rd position then the output is 1->2->3->10->NULL in forward direction and 3->2->1->NULL in the reverse direction.

Whereas if I uncomment the above code then the program simply doesnot work and and comes out after getting input

```
void insert()
{
    node *newnode,*prev,*nextnode;
    int i = 0,pos;

    nextnode = head;

    newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter the postion to be inserted : \n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    printf("Enter the data : \n");
    scanf("%d",&newnode->data);


    // newnode->next = NULL;
    // newnode->prev = NULL;

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        newnode->next = head;
        head->prev = newnode;
        head = newnode;
    }

    else
    {
        while(i<pos)
        {
            // printf("here");
            prev = nextnode;
            nextnode = nextnode->next;
            i++;
        }
        prev->next = newnode;
        //newnode->prev = prev;

        newnode->next = nextnode;
        //nextnode->prev = newnode;
    }

}

void display()
{
    node *fDisp,*lDisp;

    fDisp = head;
    lDisp = last;

    while(fDisp!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ->",fDisp->data);
        fDisp = fDisp->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");

    while(lDisp!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ->",lDisp->data);
        lDisp = lDisp->prev;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

Comment: It would help to know how `node` is declared and also `head`.

Comment: What @BoR is trying to tell you, is to please make a [mcve] of both cases. (Bo R, try typing `[mcve]` when next you write a helpful comment like that.)

Comment: @BoR :-) It felt like magic when I learned that trick. Have fun.

Comment: *"`1->2->3->10->NULL` in forward direction and `3->2->1->NULL` in the reverse direction"* suggests that you fail to update the `head->prev` node pointer correctly. See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * C program to insert a node in Doubly linked list
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * Basic structure of Node
 */
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * prev;
    struct node * next;
}*head, *last;


/*
 * Function used in this program
 */
void createList(int n);
void displayList();
void insertAtBeginning(int data);
void insertAtEnd(int data);
void insertAtN(int data, int position);


int main()
{
    int n, data, choice=1;

    head = NULL;
    last = NULL;

    /*
     * Run forever until user chooses 0
     */
    while(choice != 0)
    {
        /*
         * Menu creation to use the program
         */
        printf("============================================\n");
        printf("DOUBLY LINKED LIST PROGRAM\n");
        printf("============================================\n");
        printf("1. Create List\n");
        printf("2. Insert node - at beginning\n");
        printf("3. Insert node - at end\n");
        printf("4. Insert node - at N\n");
        printf("5. Display list\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        /*
         * Choose from different menu operation
         */
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the total number of nodes in list: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);

                createList(n);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Enter data of first node : ");
                scanf("%d", &data);

                insertAtBeginning(data);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Enter data of last node : ");
                scanf("%d", &data);

                insertAtEnd(data);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Enter the position where you want to insert new node: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                printf("Enter data of %d node : ", n);
                scanf("%d", &data);

                insertAtN(data, n);
                break;
            case 5:
                displayList();
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error! Invalid choice. Please choose between 0-5");
        }

        printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


/**
 * Creates a doubly linked list of n nodes.
 * @n Number of nodes to be created
 */
void createList(int n)
{
    int i, data;
    struct node *newNode;

    if(n >= 1)
    {
        /*
         * Create and link the head node
         */
        head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        printf("Enter data of 1 node: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);

        head->data = data;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = NULL;

        last = head;

        /*
         * Create and link rest of the n-1 nodes
         */
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

            printf("Enter data of %d node: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &data);

            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->prev = last; // Link new node with the previous node
            newNode->next = NULL;

            last->next = newNode; // Link previous node with the new node
            last = newNode;          // Make new node as last/previous node
        }

        printf("\nDOUBLY LINKED LIST CREATED SUCCESSFULLY\n");
    }
}


/**
 * Display content of the list from beginning to end
 */
void displayList()
{
    struct node * temp;
    int n = 1;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        printf("DATA IN THE LIST:\n");

        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("DATA of %d node = %d\n", n, temp->data);

            n++;

            /* Move the current pointer to next node */
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Inserts a new node at the beginning of the doubly linked list
 * @data Data of the first node i.e. data of the new node
 */
void insertAtBeginning(int data)
{
    struct node * newNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, List is Empty!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head; // Point to next node which is currently head
        newNode->prev = NULL; // Previous node of first node is NULL

        /* Link previous address field of head with newnode */
        head->prev = newNode;

        /* Make the new node as head node */
        head = newNode;

        printf("NODE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY AT THE BEGINNING OF THE LIST\n");
    }
}


/**
 * Inserts a new node at the end of the doubly linked list
 * @data Data of the last node i.e data of the new node
 */
void insertAtEnd(int data)
{
    struct node * newNode;

    if(last == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, List is empty!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->prev = last;

        last->next = newNode;
        last = newNode;

        printf("NODE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY AT THE END OF LIST\n");
    }
}


/**
 * Inserts a node at any position in the doubly linked list
 * @data Data of the new node to be inserted
 * @position Position where to insert the new node
 */
void insertAtN(int data, int position)
{
    int i;
    struct node * newNode, *temp;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, List is empty!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        i=1;

        while(i<position-1 && temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }

        if(position == 1)
        {
            insertAtBeginning(data);
        }
        else if(temp == last)
        {
            insertAtEnd(data);
        }
        else if(temp!=NULL)
        {
            newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->next = temp->next; // Connect new node with n+1th node
            newNode->prev = temp;          // Connect new node with n-1th node

            if(temp->next != NULL)
            {
                /* Connect n+1th node with new node */
                temp->next->prev = newNode;
            }
            /* Connect n-1th node with new node */
            temp->next = newNode;

            printf("NODE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY AT %d POSITION\n", position);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error, Invalid position\n");
        }
    }
}
```

You can try this program it will show you all possible operations.

Comment: You are a new member, so no dings this time, but avoid "Try this..." answers. That suggests you are unsure whether your code is correct and that the OP should just "try it". Next, "Code Only" answers are not useful. You need to explain where and what the error was and how what you did fixes it. A code only answer for an OP struggling with the language to begin with often confuses more than it helps. Your answers will be much better received if you take those suggestions into consideration.

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation. Among other reasons, that would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free programming service.